# How to loop through ADODB Connections and list Table Name, Field Name, and Field Type?

Tags: vba, excel

After doing a bit of Googling, I was able to I put together the following scrip, which lists Field Names and Data Types, but not Table Names.  I really want to list Table Name, Field Name, and Field Type (running down one row at a time).  Also, rather than hard-coding a solution, I would really prefer to loop through connection strings, as I have a bunch of ADODB connections pointing to SQL Server.

This was setup by clicking From Other Sources > From SQL Server > Server Name > Next . . . 
This is how I setup all my connection strings.

```
Sub DataExtract()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=TABLE;Data Source=SERVER"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

i = 2
With rsPubs
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    .Open "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
     For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
         Sheet1.Cells(i, 2) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
         Sheet1.Cells(i, 3) = .Fields(i - 1).Type
     Next i
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'll post my feeble script, in hope that it helps.

Comment: look at `openschema` and its associated options, you can do all you require.

Answer (score 0):

look at openschema and its associated options, you can do all you require.

`cnPubs.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)`

and

`cnPubs.OpenScheam(adSchemaColumns)`

See this link for the options.

http://www.netbox.cn/document/htm/mdcstschemaenum.htm

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work.

```
Sub DataExtractFromSQL_Server()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Data Source=SERVER_NAME"

'Now open the connection.
' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset


Worksheets(1).Cells.Clear

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Validation")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

For j = cnt To 1 Step -1

    cnPubs.Open strConn
    Set conn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(j)
    ' conn is the name of the connection string; not the connection string
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM [TABLE_PREFIX_NAME].[dbo].[" & conn & "]"
    With rsPubs

        .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
        .Open Sql
         For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
             Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1) = conn
             Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 2) = .Fields(i - 1).Name

             Select Case DataType
             Case .Fields(i - 1).Type = "200"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "VARCHAR"
             Case .Fields(i - 1).Type = "131"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "DECIMAL"
             Case .Fields(i - 1).Type = "135"
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "DATE"
             Case Else
                Worksheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 3) = "INT"
             End Select

             LastRow = LastRow + 1
         Next i
    End With
    cnPubs.Close

Next j

Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing

End Sub
```